# Not sure why XLS spreadsheets open in XML on mac's

Tags: xml, xls

Trying to troubleshoot an issue for a customer.  Whenever they export an XLS spreadsheet from our webapp, it opens to display XML.  This doesn't happen on any Windows machines.  Has anybody run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

Many libraries and programs don't actually generate XLS files when they export.  They really just generate an XML file and label it as XLS.  Since the file would have a different magic number, non-windows OSes won't necessarily treat it as a spreadsheet.

You can either switch libraries or write to a format like CSV.